# What is the equivalent of Ruby require?

Tags: python, require, equivalent

I am coming to Python from Ruby.

What is the equivalent statement of `require` in Python?

Answer (score 5):

The `import` statement.

Maybe it's advisable you follow a Python [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/tutorial/index.html) where much of the basics are explained

Comment: There is a difference between import(Python) and require(Ruby). If i require in ruby (only require statement), File can be executed whereas having only import statement does not.    For e.g. Suppose i have program(hello.rb) in ruby which has a line print "hello". I can execute this file by just doing this -> require "hello"

Comment: @abhishek, this is completely wrong. A python module __is__ executed when it is imported! How else would the classes and functions which it contains be defined?